# What tools can I use to create HTML5?

Tags: html, editor, flash-cs5

I understand that HTML5 is out. One question is that, what can I use to create HTML5? Can I use CS5 to create HTML5? I'm sorry but I'm just trying it out on my own to create HTML5.

Comment: This is a little vague.  What specific HTML5 features did you want to use?  If the answer is "none", then you're not really gaining anything by bumping a number on a doctype.

Comment: HTML5 is not "out". It is a **work in progress**.

Comment: First of all, it's wrong that HTML5 "is out". It currently has the status of a working draft. However, some features of HTML5 are already supported by some of the newer browsers, e.g. the video or the canvas elements. To get information on how to use those features, be more specific about what you want to do.

Comment: Any text editor will do to create HTML5 :)

Comment: Thanks @Felix Kling
@ Andrzej @ yuval @ simon   My bad. Sorry, I ain't aware about it. Pardon me for that. If HTML5 is out, am i able to use cs5 to create a template of it?

Comment: @FelixKling why is your response and not an (the winning) answer?

Comment: You can AJAX your HTML5 all you want with CSS3. Just remember to use RESTful services for your SOAP buzzwords in the Cloud.

Answer (score 4):

[HTML 5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) is **not** out. It is still a working draft specification.

If you follow the link, you will see on the right side - "working draft".

You can use any text editor to write HTML of any version. CS5 can also be used for it.

Comment: @Yuval A - Just the Israeli in us, urging us to immediately correct people ;)

Comment: -1, this does not answer the question.

Comment: @ashes999 - Added information that directly addresses the question.

Comment: @Oded okay, I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can even use a notepad to write HTML5. You can also use Adobe CS5 (Dreamweaver) as your HTML editor. [Adobe Dreamweaver CS5](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/)

[HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) should be a good start for you.

Comment: +1 this actually answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

hey read this online ebook dedicated to HTML5, nice one you will get whole idea about it many other knowledge

> [HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/past.html)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is a work in Progress. Some of the features in HTML5 are implemented by most browsers, some are not implemented by any browser at all. So to really work with HTML5 you have to embed yourself into the technology and test it with different browsers.

My guess is, that it will take a long time until toolsuites like CS5 have a "fire and forget" mode for HTML5. For now you can't assume that anything automatically works.

Comment: Okay understood. thanks @ mdorseif

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you read a good introduction (maybe the best) on this topic, assuming you already know what html is.

http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/